# Simple functions class

Tags: c#

I wrote this code a while back and I have recently been rewriting most of my code. I just to know if these methods can be improved. The ones that pop out to me are listed below; others don't matter as much.

Methods that need improving:

- `FilterInjectionChars`
- `IsValidAlphaNumeric`
- `FilterFigure`

```
namespace Apple.Application.Core
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;

    class AppleFunctions
    {
        private readonly HashSet<char> _allowedCharacters;

        public AppleFunctions()
        {
            _allowedCharacters = new HashSet<char>(new[] { '-', '.', ' ', 'Ã', '©', '¡', '­', 'º', '³', 'Ã', '‰', '_' });
        }

        public bool GetBoolFromEnum(string EnumValue)
        {
            return Convert.ToBoolean(EnumValue);
        }

        public bool GetBoolFromEnum(int EnumValue)
        {
            return Convert.ToBoolean(EnumValue);
        }

        public int GetEnumFromBool(bool BoolValue)
        {
            return BoolValue ? 1 : 2;
        }

        public bool IsNumber(string StringValue)
        {
            int Number;
            return int.TryParse(StringValue, out Number);
        }

        public int CompareMilleseconds(DateTime time, DateTime from)
        {
            DateTime DateTime = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
            return Convert.ToInt32((from.Subtract(DateTime).TotalMilliseconds - time.Subtract(DateTime).TotalMilliseconds));
        }

        public int GetUnixTimestamp()
        {
            return (int)DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalSeconds;
        }

        public DateTime GetUnixToDate(int unixTimeStamp)
        {
            DateTime Datetime = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, System.DateTimeKind.Utc);
            return Datetime.AddSeconds(unixTimeStamp).ToLocalTime();
        }

        public DateTime GetUnixToDate(double unixTimeStamp)
        {
            DateTime Datetime = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, System.DateTimeKind.Utc);
            return Datetime.AddSeconds(unixTimeStamp).ToLocalTime();
        }

        public int GetDateToUnix(DateTime time)
        {
            DateTime Datetime = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, System.DateTimeKind.Utc);
            return Convert.ToInt32((time - Datetime).TotalSeconds);
        }

        public string GetDateJoinString(long timeStamp) // MOVE THIS TO GROUP
        {
            string[] time = GetUnixToDate(timeStamp).ToString("MMMM/dd/yyyy").Split('/');
            return String.Format("{0} {1}, {2}", time[0].Substring(0, 3), time[1], time[2]);
        }

        public long GetNow()
        {
            double totalMilliseconds = (DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)).TotalMilliseconds;
            return ((long)totalMilliseconds);
        }

        private bool IsValidCharacter(char c)
        {
            return char.IsLetterOrDigit(c) || _allowedCharacters.Contains(c);
        }

        /* METHODS TO IMPROOVE ARE BELOW */

        public string FilterFigure(string FigureCode)
        {
            return FigureCode.Any(character => !IsValidCharacter(character)) ? "lg-3023-1335.hr-828-45.sh-295-1332.hd-180-4.ea-3168-89.ca-1813-62.ch-235-1332" : FigureCode;
        }

        public bool IsValidAlphaNumeric(string inputStr)
        {
            inputStr = inputStr.ToLower();
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(inputStr))
                return false;
            return inputStr.All(IsValidCharacter);
        }

        public string FilterInjectionChars(string input)
        {
            input = input.Replace('\u0001', ' ');
            input = input.Replace('\u0002', ' ');
            input = input.Replace('\u0003', ' ');
            input = input.Replace('\t', ' ');
            return input;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could consider using [DateTimeOffset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset(v=vs.110).aspx) rather than DateTime, since it performs all your Unix time conversion functions for you.  It is also a little nicer to work with if you have to deal with multiple time zones, as there's no longer ambiguity about what time the value *actually* represents.

Answer (score 5):

There are methods that scream louder for improvement that the three you mentioned.

For example these:

> ```
> public bool GetBoolFromEnum(string EnumValue)
> {
>   return Convert.ToBoolean(EnumValue);
> }
>
> public bool GetBoolFromEnum(int EnumValue)
> {
>   return Convert.ToBoolean(EnumValue);
> }
>
> public int GetEnumFromBool(bool BoolValue)
> {
>   return BoolValue ? 1 : 2;
> }
> ```

You are converting some enum to bool or int and back but you are not using this enum here, why?

I guess the enum look probably like this (or rather should):

```
enum State
{
    Disabled,
    Enabled,        
};
```

If you used the enum instead of just calling it like that, your methods might have be implemented as:

```
public bool ToState(State state)
{
    return Convert.ToBoolean(state);
}

public bool ToState(int state)
{
    return ToBoolean((State)state);
}

public int ToState(bool state)
{
    return Convert.ToInt32(state));
}
```

I find it very weird that you use `1` & `2` as `boolean` values instead of `1` & `0` that can be much easier converted to int/bool/enum.

Answer (score 5):

```
 public string FilterFigure(string FigureCode)
 {
     return FigureCode.Any(character => !IsValidCharacter(character)) ? "lg-3023-1335.hr-828-45.sh-295-1332.hd-180-4.ea-3168-89.ca-1813-62.ch-235-1332" : FigureCode;
 }
```

By convention, parameter names in C# should begin with a lowercase character.

Name of the method is unclear to me, as it doesn't seem to actually "filter" anything.

It performs more than one responsibility: asserting whether the code is valid, and providing a default, fallback value if it isn't. I'd move the *"lg-3023-1335..."* out of it, possibly passing it in as a parameter (`string defaultValue`, or `fallbackValue`)

```
 public bool IsValidAlphaNumeric(string inputStr)
 {
     inputStr = inputStr.ToLower();
     if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(inputStr))
         return false;
     return inputStr.All(IsValidCharacter);
 }
```

This name is off as well, it doesn't check whether the input string is alphanumeric, it tests whether it only contains '-', '.', ' ', 'Ã', '©', '¡', '­', 'º', '³', 'Ã', '‰' or '_'.

Do we need case insensitivity here, but not in `FilterFigure`? Or is this discrepancy accidental? If it's not deliberate, then I'd implement case insensitivity in `IsValidCharacter` directly, and get rid of `inputStr.ToLower()`.

Inconsistent parameter naming - other methods accept `input`, but this one takes an `inputStr`. I'd drop the "str" suffix - it's pretty clear this is a string value, no need to revive the infamous Hungarian notation.

Finally, there's some code repetition here - this bit:

```
 if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(inputStr))
     return false;
 return inputStr.All(IsValidCharacter);
```

functionally duplicates

```
 FigureCode.Any(character => !IsValidCharacter(character))
```

from `FilterFigure` (minus the case sensitivity discrepancy). Unless there are some good reasons not to do so, I'd stick to only one implementation and reuse it in both methods.

```
 public string FilterInjectionChars(string input)
 {
     input = input.Replace('\u0001', ' ');
     input = input.Replace('\u0002', ' ');
     input = input.Replace('\u0003', ' ');
     input = input.Replace('\t', ' ');
     return input;
 }
```

There's no need to reassign input over and over:

```
 public string FilterInjectionChars(string input)
 {
     return input
         .Replace('\u0001', ' ')
         .Replace('\u0002', ' ')
         .Replace('\u0003', ' ')
         .Replace('\t', ' ');
 }
```

It's simplier.

Alternatively you could use a regex pattern and get rid of all the injection chars in one go (with `Regex.Replace`) rather than one by one.

I'm not too fond of the name - it's actually filtering the injection characters *out*.

Personally I'd rename it to `RemoveInjectionChars` - somewhat clearer to me - or perhaps just `Sanitize`, which is a widely recognized synonym for this operation.